# Bazel- how to get a short but hermetic temp dir for tests?

Tags: bazel

I have a test which tries to start an embedded mysql.
It tries to write a socket file to `Files.createTempFile(null, ".sock")` which returns with the following error:
`mysql start failed with error: [ERROR] The socket file path is too long (> 103): /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/1c8ed8d84f6cb79483aa3cc4da758c86/bazel-sandbox/2478112867584790357/execroot/some_workspace/_tmp/dfebe48cda4dfdc8739653efedfa4933/394798020705754292.sock`.
I worked around it by re-pointing java temp dir to `/tmp` using `jvm_flags` but this doesn't work when I try to use sandboxing since I *guess* the test isn't allowed to write there.

I've tried setting a symbolic link from the java code (like so `Files.createSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/tmp/foo"),Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")))` but this doesn't seem to help.

I've also tried setting the `output_base` but that didn't help either.

Would really appreciate pointers and tips since I currently can't run my tests under sandbox and so can't parallelize them.

Comment: @PhilippWollermann Thanks! You're right... It seems the problem is different. In general do you think using /tmp is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach of re-pointing Java to /tmp should work. The macOS sandbox always allows writing to a number of directories and /tmp and /private/tmp [are included in this set](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/b4bf984f36766ba85abb7ac7449657fe793d1818/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/sandbox/DarwinSandboxedSpawnRunner.java#L140). I tried to reproduce the failure with a genrule: `genrule(name = "write_to_tmp", outs = ["out.txt"], cmd = "touch /tmp/something.sock && touch $@")`, which works fine and creates the file /tmp/something.sock.

I think in general using `/tmp` should work fine, although it does seem to be a bit unusual on macOS. `$TMPDIR` is set to a user-specific folder with a randomized name underneath /var/folders by the OS and it seems to be generally encouraged to use that instead of /tmp. But if you know what you're doing, I don't see a real problem.

Note that we don't have tmpfs or similar mechanisms available on macOS, so we can't automatically guarantee that your usage of writable folders like `/tmp` by actions is hermetic, won't leak state between runs or that file names won't conflict. Make sure to generate file names in a secure way via `mkstemp` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

In a bazel test, you can use the `TEST_TMPDIR` environment variable for a test-private writeable area.

See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html

Comment: It's too long. That's what I started with